# how to match a string like "[$first-last.something.random.more:junk]" using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I would like to be able to match the following:

```
[$first-last.something.random.more:junk]
```

1. $first-last  this must be either $first-last or $cat-dog (exact string match)
2. .something  can be any value ranging from a-z (upper or lower) including _- but no other characters. There may be one or more chained values (.something.something.something)
3. more:junk  the last . must be followed by a : followed by a single value containing a-z (upper or lower) as well as_-
4. steps 1-3 may repeat any number of times, separated by a comma
5. steps 1-4 must be enclosed within square brackets [ ]
6. steps 1-4 may be repeated, separated by square brackets [ ]

Examples:

```
[$first-last.something.random.more:junk]                    [correct]
[$first-last.some.more:junk, $first-last.more:values]       [correct]
[$first-last.some.more:junk, $first-last.more:values]
[$first-last.single.correct:type]                           [correct]

[$blah-garbage.some.more:junk, $first-last.more:values]     [incorrect]
[$first-last.some.more, $first-last.more:values]            [incorrect]
```

so far what i have is:

```
^\s*(\[\$[first\-last|cat\-dog]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9---_]+)+\s*:\s*+[a-zA-Z0-9---_]+(?:,\s*\$[first\-last|cat\-dog]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9---_]+)+\s*:\s*+[a-zA-Z0-9---_]+)\]\s*)\s*$
```

this does not work with this case:

```
[$first-last.some.more:junk, $first-last.more:values]
[$first-last.single.correct:type]
```

it also fails to work in Java. No error, it just says that a match could not be found even though it is valid and can find a match on the following website: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
\[(?:\$first-last|cat-dog)(?:\.[\w-]+)+[\w-]+:[\w-]+(?:,\s*(?:\$first-last|cat-dog)(?:\.[\w-]+)+[\w-]+:[\w-]+)*\]
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/HFM2J4/2)